# How to show content of a string in a popup window

Tags: php

Is there a hyperlink with onClick in php to open a popup window and display the contents of a string?

I have a string called `$data` which has a chunk of data that i would like to be displayed in a popup window..

how to go about it? i tried looking on google but couldn't find anything on this topic.

Here is a sample of my string :

```
$data = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
```

Comment: If the answer below doesn't work there must be something else wrong with the code. Please provide the relevant part of your code if you are still experiencing difficulties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$data = htmlentities(str_replace("\n", '\n', 'Your String'));
$confirm = '<a href="http://yourdomain.com?action=delete" onClick="return confirm(\'Really delete ' . $data . '?\')">Delete</a>';
echo $confirm;
?>
<script>
window.alert('<?php echo $data; ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but how to make it part of a hyperlink. I would like the popup to show when clicking on a link.

Comment: Just added that part : )

Comment: i forgot to mention i need to set this as a string to be called but doesn't seem to work? `$view = "<a href='#' onClick='return alert('<?php echo $data; ?>')'>View data</a>";` anything wrong with this?

Comment: here is the latest attempt but it doesn't popup when i call `echo $view`it just goes to the top of the same page -- `$view = "<a href='#' onClick=return alert(".$data.")>View Data</a>";`

Comment: Try this, you seem to have realised your main mistake : )

`$view = '<a href="#" onClick="return alert(' . $data  . ')">View data</a>';`

Comment: hmm, still doesn't popup though.. i click the link and it goes to the top of the page =(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77406/discussion-between-mattyf-and-user3436467).

Comment: your latest solution works better but it wont take my string into the popup. I updated my post to show you what the `$data` string looks like..

Comment: it seems perhaps window.alert cannot take a string with data which has carriage returns and html data? is there a solution to popup in normal browser popup window instead of as an alert? i've joined the chat if you would like to join also

Comment: You need to replace your new lines with `\n`

Comment: thx, i did this `$newdata = str_replace("\n", '\n', $data);` and it shows in the popup alert now :)

Comment: Updated and simplified my answer, finally got there : )